# Can I use function generator as event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a list of HTMLCollection:

```
<div class="demo">Access me by class[1]</div>
<div class="demo">Access me by class[2]</div>
<div class="demo">Access me by class[3]</div>
<div class="demo">Access me by class[4]</div>
```

And I have a script of JS:

```
var getElements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
const generatorObject = generatorFunction();

function* generatorFunction(e) { 
    for (i = 0; i < getElements.length; i++) { 
        yield getElements[i];
    }
}

generatorObject.next(); // each time pressed a key down will invoke this line 
// after invoking 6th time it will give {value: undefined, done: done}
```

My goal is to write a `keyboardEvent` based on `.addEventListener("keydown", generatorFunction)` method whereby event handler would be presented as function generator i.e. `generatorFunction` presented above. Is it good or bad practice?

Comment: You might also want to look into AsyncIterator and `for await (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator function *directly* as an event callback wouldn't make any sense because calling the function wouldn't execute its body, it would generate and return (to nowhere) an iterator.

Instead you'd need to wrap it in another function which talks to the iterator. I'm not sure exactly what your particular use case is (you talk about keydown events, but don't say on what element). But here's a general setup - in this example I'm yielding a number from an array on each keypress. On the final number, `done` is set to true.

```
function* generator() {
    let toYield = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    for (let i=0; i<toYield.length-1; i++) yield toYield[i];
    return toYield.pop(); //return final item in array, which sets iterator to done
}
const iterator = generator();
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
    let yielded = iterator.next();
    console.log(yielded);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mitya33/b24qc0ev/8/)

Comment: That should do its job. Apreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of coding with reference which I am very thankful for @Mitya

```js
var toYield;
function* generator() {
    toYield = []; // five iterable yieldedObject(s) will be pushed
    var getElements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    for (let i=0; i<getElements.length; i++) 
    yield toYield.push(getElements[i]); 
}

const iterator = generator();
var yieldedObject;
window.addEventListener('keydown', ()=> {
   yieldedObject = iterator.next();
   console.log(yieldedObject); // yieldedObject has value:xyz/undefined and flag: false/done
   colorizeIt();
});

function colorizeIt() {
for (const items of toYield){
 switch(true) {
  case yieldedObject.value >= 0:
    items.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    break;
  default:  items.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
    
    
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Accessing Elements in the DOM</title>

  <style>
    html { font-family: sans-serif; color: #333; }
    body { max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 15px; }
    div { padding: 10px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #5e41ff; }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Simple keyboard event via event generator</h1>

    <div class="demo">Access me by class[0]</div>
    <div class="demo">Access me by class[1]</div>
    <div class="demo">Access me by class[2]</div>
    <div class="demo">Access me by class[3]</div>
    <div class="demo">Access me by class[4]</div>

</body>
</html>
```

All worked just fine! Thanks a lot!